Change how JSX/TS handles prop components
I'm developing a framework which uses pseudo-JSX syntax with instructions in special attributes such as reactive, props and for etc:
interface User {
  name: string;
}

const UserDetails = (user: User) => <div>Hi {user.name}</div>;

const UserList = (manager: User, users: User[]) => (
  <div reactive>
    <UserDetails props={manager} as:manager/>
    <UserDetails for={users} as:list/>
  </div>
);

I don't execute the JSX (which gets stripped by a babel plugin) so don't have or need an h function.
It all works, but I'm having difficulty making it play nice with TypeScript, which gives me the warnings I'd expect if this was React:
 error TS2322: Type '{ props: User; "as:manager": true; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & User'.
  Property 'props' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & User'.

    <UserDetails props={manager} as:manager />

To be clear: this is how I want to use JSX in my framework. Please do not answer with how to pass props React style.
Essentially, I want to stop TypeScript from treating <UserDetails /> as a call to that function, but still detect that the name is being mentioned, so that UserDetails isn't treated as an unused variable in the module.
I am not sure if it is possible to make TS/JSX treat an element with Capitalisation as a call to a different intermediate function, which either accepts any args so that I don't get any warnings, or even better, to a function which uses the original component function's signature and allows args prop as the original prop type, and for as an array thereof.
I have tried various permutations of the following in my types file in an attempt to disable the warnings:
declare namespace JSX {
  // Empty interface to represent JSX.Element
  interface Element {
  } 

  interface ElementClass {
    [elemName: string]: any;
  }

  interface IntrinsicElements {
    [elemName: string]: any;
  }

  interface IntrinsicAttributes {
    [elemName: string]: any;
  }
}

I have also been playing around with a dummy factory which I import:
export const jsx = (tag: any, props: any, ...children: any[]) => {
  // This function can handle both lowercase and capitalized tags.
  // For simplicity, we'll just return an object representing the element.
  console.log('Factory called!');
  return { tag, props, children };
};
export const jsxs = jsx;

However I'm not sure that ever runs as I get no console log when I run:
npx ts-node src/index.tsx

Here is my tsconfig:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "jsxImportSource": "path/to/jsx-factory", 
    "jsxFactory": "jsx",
  }
}

The jsxImportSource path is correct as I get a warning otherwise.
Just for fun, or in case this leads to a solution, TypeScript gives me no warnings if I do this, and the function is seen as being used. I can easily strip that with Babel but its obviously not as pretty:
<UserDetails.name />
<UserDetails.call />

